# Creating Hyperledger Sawtooth network

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I am setting up a multi-node Hyperledger Sawtooth network using Docker images. I am able to bring up Sawtooth Validator, Settings TP and intkey TP on 3 AWS VMs, however, the Validators are not able to connect each other. I am getting the following error:

Attempted to remove send_message function for connection OutboundConnectionThread-tcp://3.xxx.xxx.xxx:8800, but no send_message function was registered
WARNING dispatch] Attempted to remove send_last_message function for connection OutboundConnectionThread-tcp://3.xxx.xxx.xxx:8800, but no send_last_message function was registered

Any pointers to resolve the issue would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer I posted in https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/sawtooth

That looks like a ZMQ error. It was not able to connect, so it had an error when it was disconnecting during cleanup when the task was ending. The real error should be earlier. But I think the root cause is lack of network connectivity. Try these tips and see if they help:
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/faq/installation/#i-get-this-error-after-setting-up-a-sawtooth-network-can-t-send-message-ping-response-back-to-because-connection-outboundconnectionthread-tcp-192-168-0-100-8800-not-in-dispatcher